# "I'll come eaten" - is it correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Check these sentences with their context -

> Today, you got an interview and the interviewers may ask about their company and some questions about the current affairs ~ Yes I know. Don't worry, I'll **come prepared.** 
>   (A cop to another cop) There's some illegal activity going on in Dawn's Street and tonight, we have to fix that ~ Sure, sir! I'll **come armed.**

Now, is this possible that way?

> We'll be back by evening but then remember, that place is very far and no food is available ~ Dont' worry, I'll **come eaten.**

**"...come eaten"** - possible this way? If not, how do I say it in **that format** without changing the sentence completely?

Comment: You can say, "I'll come having eaten," or, "I'll come full," (or even, "I won't come hungry").

Comment: @J.R. But if I'll come dressed or armed is okay, why not I'll come eaten. We don't usually say I'll come having armed/dressed where *to have* is not eating but rather possession.

Comment: It's a quirk of the language, I guess. But remember, _have_ is about [so much more than possession](http://www.onelook.com/?w=have&ls=a).

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to snip the co-text, but I'm keeping it in mind.

> I'll come armed

This means that the cop is going to be *armed* when he *comes*.

> I'll come eaten

This means that I'm going to be *eaten* when I *come*.

Grammatically sound, but semantically nonsensical.

Generally you can only *verb-of-motion* *past-tense* when the past-tense describes an act that you will have been done to *yourself* (Or to the subject of the main clause.

For instance:

- I will come dressed = I will come, having been dressed
- I will come armed = I will come, having been armed
- He will come groomed - He will come, having been groomed

... etc.

If you want to say that you have come, having eaten beforehand... well, that's probably the only way to say it:

- I will come, having already eaten

Comment: *remove **myself*** and it'll go fine. *I'll dress and come.* *I'll arm and come* **and so...** I'll eat and come.* - what about that?

Comment: @MaulikV Well, that would work, but Codeswitcher has provided an _unusual reading_ that people might have.

Comment: These sentences don't specify who did the dressing, arming, or grooming.  In "I will come dressed", for example, the speaker could be dressed by a servant.  In "I will come armed", someone else could have armed the speaker.  It's true that most people dress themselves, so it's a reasonable guess, but the sentence doesn't specify one way or the other.  In "I'll come eaten", the guess is perhaps less reasonable.

Comment: Yeah,true. It's actually passivisation, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Important point 1:

If one says, "I will come prepared," who is the object of "prepared"?  "I" am "prepared".

If one says, "I will come armed," who is the object of "armed"?  "I" am "armed".

Thus if one says, "I will come eaten," who is the object of "eaten"?  "I" am "eaten".

Thus literally, "I will come eaten" does not mean "I will have ate (something)", it means "(something) ate me".

Important point 2:

The passive "to be eaten" is extremely vulgar slang for a sexual act involving a mouth.  The verb "come" is also vulgar slang.  The sentence "I will come eaten" is a perfectly valid, intelligible English sentence **that means something radically other than what you intend and you must never, ever use it in polite company.**

Comment: I didn't even consider this reading, and would be very surprised if anyone I spoke to thought of it. But yes, perhaps best to play it safe.

Comment: In that sense... *I'll come prepared - who has prepared? 'you' have (the *subject*); Likewise, who has armed? 'you' have; who has eaten? 'you' have. In your all examples, the object is served as a noun *to be*. *'You' being prepared; 'you' being armed'; 'you' **being eaten.*** -which is not true.

Comment: @MaulikV: Nope.

Answer (score 3):

*I will come fed* conveys the meaning you intend and would be understood by native speakers.  However in British English it isn't common usage except for comic effect.

Answer (score 0):

An english person would say

Don't worry, I will already have eaten

or

No problem, I will already have eaten

Answer (score 0):

If something is eaten it is down in the stomach. If you are eaten (eg by a bear) you won't go anywhere. Your sentence makes no sense.